# Scala Play 2.0.2 multiple file upload

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am new to Play and scala. My requirement is to provide a browse button where we can select multiple files and upload those files. Here is code I have written:

in the scala.html file:

```
<input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" id="files" size="30">
```

in the Controller:

```
def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
  request.body.file("files").map { picture =>
    import java.io.File
    val filename = picture.filename 
    val contentType = picture.contentType
    picture.ref.moveTo(new File("/tmp/picture"))
    Ok("File uploaded")
  }.getOrElse {
    Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
      "error" -> "Missing file"
    )
  }
}
```

But I am not able to upload multiple files. Any idea what is the issue here?

Comment: What actually happens when you upload multiple files ?are they silently ignored ? do you get an error message ?

Comment: can anyone tell me how to get? i mean the uploaed picture size.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you do not need

```
="multiple"
```

This works equivalently

```
<input type="file" name="files" multiple id="files" size="30">
```

---

To load in multiple files, when defining your form must have the attribute

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

For example, if using the helpers

```
@helper.form(action = routes.MyController.submit(), 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data", 'id -> "myform")
```

or if you're not

```
<form action=... enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
```

In your controller you want to try something like this (for Java, I'm sure its similar in Scala)

```
//Get all files bound to the form when submitted 
List<FilePart> plate_files = request().body().asMultipartFormData().getFiles();
//Get files from a specific name or id
FilePart myfile = request().body().asMultipartFormData().getFile("files");
```

Then you can use these the iterate through the FilePart objects

Hopefully its similar in scala

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this as well if you like:

```
def uploadFiles: Action[AnyContent] { request =>
  val files: Option[Seq[FilePart[TemporaryFile]]] = request.body.asMultipartFormData.map(_.files)
   val filesJavaIO: Option[Seq[File]] = files map { fileSeq => fileSeq map { file =>
    file.ref.moveTo(new File("/tmp/myFiles"))
  }
  }
Ok("File uploaded")

}
```

Comment: request.body.files map { file => file.ref.moveTo(new File("/tmp/myfiles/"+file.filename)) }

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple, Just look at this working code -

```
def uploadAll = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
  val files = request.body.files.toArray
  files.foreach(file => {
    val filename = Paths.get(file.filename).getFileName
    file.ref.moveTo(Paths.get(s"C:/Users/tusharw/Documents/Play Uploads/$filename"), replace = true)
  })
  Ok("Files uploaded")
}
```

**Or, as per @robor78 said, this is more simpler way -**

```
def uploadAll = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
  request.body.files map { file =>
    file.ref.moveTo(Paths.get("C:/Users/tusharw/Documents/Play Uploads/"+file.filename), replace = true)
  }
  Ok("Files uploaded")
}
```

And add `multiple` to your input. That's it!

> Note  that, here `Paths` belongs to `java.nio.file.Paths`. You may use `new File("/somepath")` instead.